# Hide element on xs devices

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I cannot find the answer neither on StackOverflow or the React-bootstrap-site.

How do I hide an element ( for example) on xs devices, soemthing like xs-hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to hide only on xs rezolutions the class is **hidden-xs**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 18):

For Bootstrap version 4 beta you will need to use `<Col className="d-none d-sm-block">` to hide the columns on xs screens

Comment: Just confirming that this works with `react-bootstrap` (1.6.1) on React 17+

Comment: Confirming this works with `react-bootstrap` 2.7.4, `bootstrap` 5.3.0, and React 18.2.

Answer (score 11):

I am using reactstrap. This works for me

`<Col lg="6" className="d-none d-lg-block">`

Basically takes half the width in large screens, and 0 width in screen sizes md, sm, xs

Answer (score 1):

try:
`<Col xsHidden />`
- and/or the other usual bootstrap values e.g.  mdHidden, lgHidden

Comment: @martin36 I think the more accurate comment is "this appears to no longer work with react-bootstrap" - as my comment is some 18 months old now, and react-bootstrap has changed quite a lot in that time! In fact, everything has changed quite a lot in 18 months, for instance I have written out all bootstrap from my active projects. I've found flex box to be far better than Grid/Row/Col

Answer (score 0):

in latest version, Bootstrap 5, you can use class name. For the question, you can use this `d-xs-none`. If you want hide in mobile but display in tablet screen, the class should be like this: `d-xs-none d-md-block`